# AVFoundation Swift Error

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

Im trying to create some background music for my game and Im getting the following error with my code:

```
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

    class GameScene: SKScene {

    let ballCategoryName = "ball"
    let paddCategoryName = "paddle"
    let brickCategoryName = "brick"

    let backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override init(size: CGSize){
        super.init(size: size)

        let bgMusicURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("bgMusic", withExtension: "mp3")

        backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicURL, error: nil);

        backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1


    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

The error is on the line:

```
backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicURL, error: nil)
```

How can i fix this error. It says cannot assign backgroundMusicPlater in self. Also I have the mp3 named exactly as in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your backgroundMusicPlayer is a `let` constant:

```
let backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

If you want to mutate that variable, change the `let` to `var`.